# What is error number -214722098

Tags: vbscript, vb6

This error is being returned from a VB application. We're trying to send mail using SMTP with Amazon SES.  Knowing what the error code is would help to determine if it is a code error, connection or something on the Amazon side.

Comment: One digit is missing in the error code...

Comment: It would be a lot easier to tell you what kind of error this is if you decided to disclose the code that is raising it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [hrplus10.exe](ftp://ftp.pl.freebsd.org/vol/rzm1/simtelnet/win95/prog/hrplus10.zip) to lookup any HRESULT code.

Btw, you are missing a digit indeed.